# Understanding deleting item from a list in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivymd

I am struggling to delete an item from a list and have hit the wall of confusion. I am building a car maintenance tracking app and have taken the relevant sections to reproduce the section I am struggling with below.

I am using the kivy storage module to store the items (maintenance.json). I was unable to get the list to show up on entering the screen in my main app, so View Service button loads the list as follows (I think):

- delete any children from ids.scroll
- load key and values from JSON
- create a three item list (service list)
- create a child widget for the IRightBodyTouch

I attempted to add a lambda function to the MinusSign to remove the corresponding three line item but fail to understand the path of parent/children to remove corresponding item. I have onliy figured out how to remove children[0]

Here the x is the minus icon pressed, which is a child of MinusSign.

`on_release= lambda x: self.trash(x.parent)`

We can see the parameter passed is that MinusSign which corresponds to which button is clicked. Here is what I believe the hierarchy to be from executing trash() below:

Couldn't get formatting to work so picture included:

[Parent/Child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgtpM.png)

I am confused and lost on how to remove ThreeLineItemAvatarList when IconRightWidget is clicked. I appreciate any insights and help, thanks!

```
def trash(self, thing):
        print(thing) # __main__.MinusSign object at 0x7f35dae1ed60
        print(thing.parent) #kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x7f35dadba9e0>
        print(self.ids.scroll.children) # kivymd.uix.list.list.ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem object at 0x7f1d8a3c6ac0
        print(self.ids.scroll.parent) # kivymd.uix.scrollview.MDScrollView object at 0x7f1d8aff79a0>
        print(self.ids.scroll.parent.parent) # kivymd.uix.boxlayout.MDBoxLayout object at 0x7f1d8afdaac0
        self.ids.service_box.remove_widget(thing) # does nothing
```

maintenance.json

```
{"oil change": {"interval_mileage": "5,000", "interval_month": "6"}, "transmission": {"interval_mileage": "35,000", "interval_month": "24"}, "tire rotation": {"interval_mileage": "5,000", "interval_month": ""}, "headlight": {"interval_mileage": "67890", "interval_month": ""}, "gasloine": {"interval_mileage": "100", "interval_month": "NA"}}
```

main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch, IconRightWidget, ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem, IRightBodyTouch

Builder.load_string("""
<AddRemoveService>
    name: 'service_screen'
    GridLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.9
        size_hint_x: 1
        cols: 1
        rows: 3

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: "25dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x" : 0.5}
            size_hint: (0.5, 0.5)

            MDTextField:
                id: service
                hint_text: "Enter service"
                size_hint: (0.5, 0.3)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                helper_text: "Please enter service to add"
                helper_text_mode: "on_error"

            MDTextField:
                id: interval_miles
                hint_text: "Enter mileage interval"
                size_hint: (0.5, 0.3)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                helper_text: "Please enter mileage interval of service"
                helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                spacing: "20dp"

            MDTextField:
                id: interval_months
                hint_text: "Enter month interval"
                size_hint: (0.5, 0.3)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                helper_text: "Please enter month interval of service"
                helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                spacing: "20dp"

            MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                id: send_service
                icon: "car-cog"
                font_size: "22dp"
                text: "Send Service"
                on_press: root.add_service(); root.load_service_items()
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                size_hint: (0.5, 0.3)
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                spacing: "20dp"

            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                padding: "25dp"
                # md_bg_color: 0, 0, 1, 0.2
                pos_hint: {"center_x" : 0.5, "center_y": 1}
                size_hint: (1, 0.1)
                spacing: "15dp"

            MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                id: list_service
                icon: "list-box"
                font_size: "22dp"
                text: "View Service"
                on_press: root.load_service_items()
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                size_hint: (0.5, 0.3)
                # padding: "25dp"
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                spacing: "20dp"


        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: "25dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x" : 0.5}
            id: service_box
            size_hint: (0.5, 0.3)

            MDScrollView:

                MDList:
                    id: scroll

""")

# Declare both screens
class AddRemoveService(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.service_save = JsonStore((f'maintenance.json'))

    def load_service_items(self):

        serviceList = ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem
        j = 0
        value1 = ""
        value2 = ""

        try:

            for count in self.service_save.keys():
               self.ids.scroll.remove_widget(
               self.ids.scroll.children[0])

        except:
            pass

        for service_items in self.service_save.keys():
            for interval in self.service_save.get(service_items):
                if j == 0:
                    value1 = (self.service_save.get(service_items)[interval])
                    j = 1


                else:
                    value2 = (self.service_save.get(service_items)[interval])
                    if value2 == "":
                        value2 = "N/A"
                    j = 0

                    self.ids.scroll.add_widget(
                        serviceList(
                            MinusSign(
                                IconRightWidget(
                                    icon = "minus",
                                    on_release= lambda x: self.trash(x.parent)
                                    ),
                                ),
                            text = f"{service_items}",
                            secondary_text = f"{value1} miles",
                            tertiary_text = f"{value2} months"
                             )
                                                        )
def trash(self, thing):
        print(thing) # __main__.MinusSign object at 0x7f35dae1ed60
        print(thing.parent) #kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x7f35dadba9e0>
        print(self.ids.scroll.children)
        print(self.ids.scroll.parent)
        print(self.ids.scroll.parent.parent)
        self.ids.service_box.remove_widget(thing)



        # check if boxes are set and send
    def add_service(self):

        if self.ids.service.text != "" and self.ids.interval_miles.text != "":
            self.service_save.put(self.ids.service.text,
                                  interval_mileage = self.ids.interval_miles.text,
                                  interval_month = self.ids.interval_months.text)
            self.ids.service.error = False
            self.ids.service.error = False
        else:
            self.ids.service.error = True
            self.ids.interval_miles.error = True

class MinusSign(IRightBodyTouch, MDBoxLayout):
    adaptive_width = True

class TestApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        # Create the screen manager
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(AddRemoveService(name='menu'))

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhQU5.png)

self.ids.service_box.remove_widget(thing) # does nothing expect it to remove list